# What is the correct way for a client to store a CSRF token?

Tags: csrf, csrf-token

I make a call to a server on the `/login` endpoint, and it returns a session cookie as well as CSRF token in the return values (cannot store this as a cookie as it is not secure). Where can I store the CSRF value on the client so I can use it in my calls to the server? If it is just in the JS memory, I lose it as soon as I leave the page even if my session is still valid, and storing as a cookie is not secure. Or is it not possible to store and I have to hit an endpoint to get one every time I close the page?

Comment: The common way to do this is for the server to render the token into the page body, e.g. as a hidden field, which will be submitted when the form is submitted. The token is generally not persisted between pages.

Comment: @JohnWu I see. If I was doing pure client side rendering how would I approach this?

Comment: I suppose you could return the token in the AJAX response (or whatever data retrieval method the page uses) and store it in a Javascript variable.

Answer (score 0):

Store it in Localstorage, because no other front end domain can access to your csrfToken as it is stored in association with your front end domain.

For example, **hacker.com** can't access csrfToken from localStorage set on **your-domain.com**

But I still trying to know if hacker can trick things with subdomain as **your-domain.com**.

```
<body>
<form class="form" action="bankApi/bank-transfer" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="account" value="456" />
  <input type="text" name="amount" value="1000000" />
  <input type="submit" value="Click me!" />
</form>

<script>
  const form = document.querySelector(".form");
  // Extracting csrfToken from localStorage for this hacker.com domain is NOT possible. 
  form.submit();
</script>
```